# Firestore Security Rules for Query with IN

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am doing a query

```
firestore().collection('stories')
        .where('published', '==', true)
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', storyIds)
        .get()
```

I have a rule for stories

```
match /stories/{storyId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.published == true;
}
```

And getting an error **[firestore/permission-denied]** if there is id of unpublished story in my list.
What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATED**

```
storyIds=["story2","story3"]
```

**Firestore Docs**

**Story2**
[image: story2 doc]

**Story3**
[image: story3 doc]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of document from Firebase console that you think should match the query? Also try `console.log(storyIds)` and share the output

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. Just added my `documentId` in document as `id` and changed query.

```
firestore().collection('stories')
        .where('published', '==', true)
        .where('id', 'in', storyIds)
        .get()
```

This works now.